# How to get hash value of a text saved in a database

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, cryptography

I'm working with a web application and I want to get the hash value of the text which is saved in a MySQL database table,I'm new to this field and I'm using Spring-MVC for the web application,can any one please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By hash, are you talking about any specific hashing function?  A common one that you can use is md5, which mysql supports:

```
select md5(some_column) from some_table;
```

Here's a link to the reference: [Mysql Reference/Encryption Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/encryption-functions.html)

Comment: Isn't it `md5('some text')` instead of `some_column`? Don't advise the broken MD5 instead of SHA-2 functionality unless you understand the implications.

Comment: The original poster wanted to get the hash value of the text which is saved in a table!  You can conveniently get a hash of the string directly in the table, using the md5 function directly on the column.  MD5 is great for simple purposes of generating a smaller token for uniqueness.  But you are correct that it should no longer be used for security purposes.

Comment: If you want a smaller value then use SHA-2 256 or 512 bit hashing, and only use the X leftmost bytes. This is secure, until of course the number of bits gets too small. It depends on the context if MD5's vulnerabilities are an issue or not, but as it is easily replaced, I would never bet on MD5 anymore.